# How to properly escape an ampersand in an execution statement

Tags: powershell

Quick question regarding the proper way to escape the ampersand in my statement below, which is just a command-line execution.

```
& $CmdLine -f:passwordFile.txt /A:Coreplan /U:admin /D:BalSheet /R:global_General_Assets_P&E
```

I have tried a number of different iterations of quotes with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampersand does not require special escaping if it is in a single- or double-quoted string.

```
& $CmdLine -f:passwordFile.txt /A:Coreplan /U:admin /D:BalSheet '/R:global_General_Assets_P&E'
```

or

```
& $CmdLine -f:passwordFile.txt /A:Coreplan /U:admin /D:BalSheet "/R:global_General_Assets_P&E"
```

should work.  This is assuming `$cmdline` contains just the path to an exe.  Make sure `$cmdLine` does not contain any additional arguments...

And like Ansgar suggests, please provide the error details if these approaches don't work.

Comment: This worked.  I went with quotes because that's a format I'm more comfortable with.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell's escape character is the backquote (`` ` ``), so try changing `/R:global_General_Assets_P&E` to `` /R:global_General_Assets_P`&E ``:

```
& $CmdLine -f:passwordFile.txt /A:Coreplan /U:admin /D:BalSheet /R:global_General_Assets_P`&E
```

If that doesn't work: please update your question with the error message you're getting.

Comment: Thanks, this still reported an error:  'E' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Try belt and suspenders: ``/R:"global_General_Assets_P`&E"``

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that `$CmdLine` is an executable or batch file you are wanting call and the rest of the line is the set of parameters you want to send to $CmdLine.

You can try something like this:

```
& $CmdLine "-f:passwordFile.txt" "/A:Coreplan" "/U:admin" "/D:BalSheet" "/R:global_General_Assets_P&E"
```

Comment: This passes a single string argument to the executable containing `-f:passwordFile.txt /A:Coreplan /U:admin /D:BalSheet /R:global_General_Assets_P&E`

Comment: You are correct and that made the answer confusing.  I have updated the answer with the correction.  The important point is that powershell will ignore the `&` if it is encapsulated with single or double quotes no matter how many parameters are in the parameter array.